# Parsing txt file c++ and string

Tags: string, arduino, arduino-c++

Hi I am working with c++ and String class (Arduino).

I want to obain a String variable in this format

```
String CERT_TEST = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
                   "MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA3Iys1ic34J0eaUkr+q0UXIR5R55KHNWN4ABNhPpA7auaUwyq\n"
                   "F4yyBinBlObuMrrtFrMJX+nvs2TywVtKjeWyP73/JXilMFiW0ssOzZnh4owB7mGt\n"
                   "jwYNQELVVW7LUzikywNv6rhl4t1YFMP+byFyagle37BA+ZJ0kA9/6dNgzdTDDgwS\n"
                   "64dyWDeqKMfFGn6McrjttPNnNEx3YPmbHf2MT3Tz0KIhJoZoDNSiGfWuPYTkEs6G\n"
                   "saSDVvr4ZbCWnaD5OFk/1d7mtF2CoAtwIrc5RJxKYfgPOo0RCvxu76pUWWR2+UYo\n"
                   "fw6B1AI3d6eRcjWLO5u2KCfBNkPaRcq5kDGmiwIDAQABAoIBAHemEbX0fMnsMy1n\n"
                   "Nua9swgmDi2eYBKYgGl/gI6dvU+zAvv/KN+xwnq5eH2xcpQu+KSR6IoSPaoTH+dq\n"
                   "AV5NuJAAIUVQ2D0MMnaVFqjPzM28queKMkAfRl0QZO/+NWwmlLBWYwbxlsSm1Dwf\n"
                   "wA7GFG4WO1QbKIS8wWPOJNTTifbfbazP7mpEOrc02i9vidRLFszcIKXU4N7OC/NI\n"
                   "1yYKdgaZQX9eAiFLmIPbgSm3R1diKLr6SboRH2lrnRIH6tyooieEq9VmaExin69t\n"
                   "hRC5oCpz1yXEezYmyvkJDN9Snvj5ARFw8x1mgI2AZWvX9H/imHI4aw5228YKhhGQ\n"
                   "Wjzy29ECgYEA/os7Cxs9Txp2GHIKpbeg9witADiVu8MVcAWvVXrdLZJjAB5IBpxF\n"
                   "5M5KKJhS5xbnN8JHCZCqZUqBuEzggGSaDJ0dun0gzXSPVVJCQviiqw368Rf5aDGc\n"
                   "NDHp8W5J+cGuCRNV7H+pW+paxbNRPgpMcClk779mvR2pvAdzzMfwF6cCgYEA3c+p\n"
                   "P0TfWZQxG0COBf/EqaXCYx/14RntFyiuPPKBalor+SK5QJO+dkJFQgMQxtf6SGFi\n"
                   "kyxyvaWhoE9iVUsafST39TIh+8tTkcqD8vSMVWNQvKf9ha2yzWIFpUNI1eTMooAg\n"
                   "NphKE0OM5bvF+K7edhd2xtIJn0yzjIItifhcVn0CgYEA4yttOV9JGyTZir2UpQs6\n"
                   "G95hT5Ywg876feyE63vokzhXJI7h5wxnEGnPI2W2b0kwd8HqVi4G9LlHBi2OGugt\n"
                   "194M3xe3Q8Wn+hSc0FpICvNCJxMnYocMCkUVrYOpf74LzUu1Xokco8yG0HRVqFHW\n"
                   "oC9BRvqB/XvQtN/NyFAUBXcCgYEAnM7gzIypBVABg02Y2d7eLjyz9pWyoqdMeHHW\n"
                   "89lQ6lnC+oa0xlVscXgaNDeslZY8Jw1JvdfPagj9ATL9xmSo3k3TSbFeWv58HvY3\n"
                   "X/vIddkXS7fLP8TzQcUJTrMJe8Ubccn4fAAfZgz8P7EGnO8q7/tYiegUy1xTFoM1\n"
                   "JHPC+5UCgYEAp3d6hOl1MMSLqVajk8AS8o6AHJbVY4LYg5dXWP6AEl8xvnfXnhW0\n"
                   "H0rMJmHZcW4+2gXIMd5/G9mJnaz8jqtzcyyH4ysBJR+DepGeISZkCjuAUNwAd8UG\n"
                   "+Ttzy6ZXy6OKCv6lJW0U9S+wub1hbEUKKH4tRx1c6BoI8CmwqnfeX4M=\n"
                   "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

Starting from a txt file where the information is stored in the following way ..

```
AWS_CERT_PRIVATE: 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA3Iys1ic34J0eaUkr+q0UXIR5R55KHNWN4ABNhPpA7auaUwyq\n
F4yyBinBlObuMrrtFrMJX+nvs2TywVtKjeWyP73/JXilMFiW0ssOzZnh4owB7mGt\n
jwYNQELVVW7LUzikywNv6rhl4t1YFMP+byFyagle37BA+ZJ0kA9/6dNgzdTDDgwS\n
64dyWDeqKMfFGn6McrjttPNnNEx3YPmbHf2MT3Tz0KIhJoZoDNSiGfWuPYTkEs6G\n
saSDVvr4ZbCWnaD5OFk/1d7mtF2CoAtwIrc5RJxKYfgPOo0RCvxu76pUWWR2+UYo\n
fw6B1AI3d6eRcjWLO5u2KCfBNkPaRcq5kDGmiwIDAQABAoIBAHemEbX0fMnsMy1n\n
Nua9swgmDi2eYBKYgGl/gI6dvU+zAvv/KN+xwnq5eH2xcpQu+KSR6IoSPaoTH+dq\n
AV5NuJAAIUVQ2D0MMnaVFqjPzM28queKMkAfRl0QZO/+NWwmlLBWYwbxlsSm1Dwf\n
wA7GFG4WO1QbKIS8wWPOJNTTifbfbazP7mpEOrc02i9vidRLFszcIKXU4N7OC/NI\n
1yYKdgaZQX9eAiFLmIPbgSm3R1diKLr6SboRH2lrnRIH6tyooieEq9VmaExin69t\n
hRC5oCpz1yXEezYmyvkJDN9Snvj5ARFw8x1mgI2AZWvX9H/imHI4aw5228YKhhGQ\n
Wjzy29ECgYEA/os7Cxs9Txp2GHIKpbeg9witADiVu8MVcAWvVXrdLZJjAB5IBpxF\n
5M5KKJhS5xbnN8JHCZCqZUqBuEzggGSaDJ0dun0gzXSPVVJCQviiqw368Rf5aDGc\n
NDHp8W5J+cGuCRNV7H+pW+paxbNRPgpMcClk779mvR2pvAdzzMfwF6cCgYEA3c+p\n
P0TfWZQxG0COBf/EqaXCYx/14RntFyiuPPKBalor+SK5QJO+dkJFQgMQxtf6SGFi\n
kyxyvaWhoE9iVUsafST39TIh+8tTkcqD8vSMVWNQvKf9ha2yzWIFpUNI1eTMooAg\n
NphKE0OM5bvF+K7edhd2xtIJn0yzjIItifhcVn0CgYEA4yttOV9JGyTZir2UpQs6\n
G95hT5Ywg876feyE63vokzhXJI7h5wxnEGnPI2W2b0kwd8HqVi4G9LlHBi2OGugt\n
194M3xe3Q8Wn+hSc0FpICvNCJxMnYocMCkUVrYOpf74LzUu1Xokco8yG0HRVqFHW\n
oC9BRvqB/XvQtN/NyFAUBXcCgYEAnM7gzIypBVABg02Y2d7eLjyz9pWyoqdMeHHW\n
89lQ6lnC+oa0xlVscXgaNDeslZY8Jw1JvdfPagj9ATL9xmSo3k3TSbFeWv58HvY3\n
X/vIddkXS7fLP8TzQcUJTrMJe8Ubccn4fAAfZgz8P7EGnO8q7/tYiegUy1xTFoM1\n
JHPC+5UCgYEAp3d6hOl1MMSLqVajk8AS8o6AHJbVY4LYg5dXWP6AEl8xvnfXnhW0\n
H0rMJmHZcW4+2gXIMd5/G9mJnaz8jqtzcyyH4ysBJR+DepGeISZkCjuAUNwAd8UG\n
+Ttzy6ZXy6OKCv6lJW0U9S+wub1hbEUKKH4tRx1c6BoI8CmwqnfeX4M=\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I have done this code

```
   String result;
  while (file.available())
  {
    result.concat(file.readStringUntil('\n'));
  }

  file.close();
```

but i obtain this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA3Iys1ic34J0eaUkr+q0UXIR5R55KHNWN4ABNhPpA7auaUwyq\nF4yyBinBlObuMrrtFrMJX+nvs2TywVtKjeWyP73/JXilMFiW0ssOzZnh4owB7mGt\njwYNQELVVW7LUzikywNv6rhl4t1YFMP+byFyagle37BA+ZJ0kA9/6dNgzdTDDgwS\n64dyWDeqKMfFGn6McrjttPNnNEx3YPmbHf2MT3Tz0KqKMfFGn6McrjttPNnNEx3YPmbHf2MT3Tz0KIhJoZoDNSiGfWuPYTkEs6G\nsaSDVvr4ZbCWnaD5OFk/1d7mtF2CoAtwIrc5RJxKYfgPOo0RCvxu76pUWWR2+UYo\nfw6B1AI3d6eRcjWLO5u2KCfBNkPaRcq5kDGmiwIDAQABAoIBAHemEbX0fMnsMy1n\nNua9swgmDi2eYBKYgGl/gI6dvU+zAvv/KN+xwnq5eH2xcpQMnaVFqjPzM28queKMkAfRl0QZO/+NWwmlLBu+KSR6IoSPaoTH+dq\nAV5NuJAAIUVQ2D0MMnaVFqjPzM28queKMkAfRl0QZO/+NWwmlLBWYwbxlsSm1Dwf\nwA7GFG4WO1QbKIS8wWPOJNTTifbfbazP7mpEOrc02i9vidRLFszcIKXU4N7OC/NI\n1yYKdgaZQX9eAiFLmIPbgSm3R1diKLr6SboRH2lrnRIH6tyooieEq9VmaExin69t\nhRC5oCpz1yXEezYmyvkJDHIKpbeg9witADiVu8MVcAWvVXrdLZJjAB5IN9Snvj5ARFw8x1mgI2AZWvX9H/imHI4aw5228YKhhGQ\nWjzy29ECgYEA/os7Cxs9Txp2GHIKpbeg9witADiVu8MVcAWvVXrdLZJjAB5IBpxF\n5M5KKJhS5xbnN8JHCZCqZUqBuEzggGSaDJ0dun0gzXSPVVJCQviiqw368Rf5aDGc\nNDHp8W5J+cGuCRNV7H+pW+paxbNRPgpMcClk779mvR2pvAdzzMfwF6cCgYEA3SMVWNQvKf9ha2yzWIFpUNI1eTMooAg\nNphc+p\nP0TfWZQxG0COBf/EqaXCYx/14RntFyiuPPKBalor+SK5QJO+dkJFQgMQxtf6SGFi\nkyxyvaWhoE9iVUsafST39TIh+8tTkcqD8vSMVWNQvKf9ha2yzWIFpUNI1eTMooAg\nNphKE0OM5bvF+K7edhd2xtIJn0yzjIItifhcVn0CgYEA4yttOV9JGyTZir2UpQs6\nG95hT5Ywg876feyE63vokzhXJI7h5wxnEGnY2d7eLjyz9pWyoqdMeHHW\n89lQ6lnC+oa0PI2W2b0kwd8HqVi4G9LlHBi2OGugt\n194M3xe3Q8Wn+hSc0FpICvNCJxMnYocMCkUVrYOpf74LzUu1Xokco8yG0HRVqFHW\noC9BRvqB/XvQtN/NyFAUBXcCgYEAnM7gzIypBVABg02Y2d7eLjyz9pWyoqdMeHHW\n89lQ6lnC+oa0xlVscXgaNDeslZY8Jw1JvdfPagj9ATL9xmSo3k3TSbFeWv58HvY3\nX/vIddkXS7fLP8TzQcUJTrMJe8Ubccn4fAAfZgz8P7EG7fLP8TzQcUJTrMJe8Ubccn4fAAfZgz8P7EGnO8q7/tYiegUy1xTFoM1\nJHPC+5UCgYEAp3d6hOl1MMSLqVajk8AS8o6AHJbVY4LYg5dXWP6AEl8xvnfXnhW0\nH0rMJmHZcW4+2gXIMd5/G9mJnaz8jqtzcyyH4ysBJR+DepGeISZkCjuAUNwAd8UG\n+Ttzy6ZXy6OKCv6lJW0U9S+wub1hbEUKKH4tRx1c6BoI8Cmwq---\nnfeX4M=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

instead of

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The difference it is that i want to concatenate vertically all the rows

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: add a line break after you added a line. Or simply read all the contents rather than only the lines and stripping the newlines

Comment: btw ... did you just post a private key online? Your admin will not be amused

Comment: how can i add a line break building the string ? Can you post the code ?  it is a fake private key...

Comment: i do not know arduinos c++ dialect. If I knew what `file` is, I would read documentation. My first guess would be that `readUntil` has an overload without parameter, or maybe not. Seems like `readUntil` was the wrong choice to begin with, because you simply want to read it all. What is `file`? Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You read the lines until terminator `'\n'`. Not including it.

Why do you expect the concatenated string to contain line breaks?

If you would read the manual instead of blindly using stuff you would have noticed

> ### Notes and Warnings
>
> The terminator character is discarded from the stream.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadstringuntil/

As mentioned in the comments you should simply read the entire file instead of reading it line-wise.

Comment: Ok i changed the code in the following way     String result2;
  while (file.available())
  {
    result.concat(file.readString());
  }